# See full list of recipients in the send email activity

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I need to remove one email recipient from the list of about 6. Unfortunately, I can only see the first 2-3 users. The one I need to remove is hidden within the ellipses entry. Is there a way to see the full list and remove just one person I need?

It looks like I have to remove all people and add every one back again, which is really awkward.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange, but this depends on the way you open "Select Users" dialog.

- *Right clicking* the activity, and opening `Properties` gives you this 'Send an Email Properties' window, and clicking `...` there results in 'Select Users' window **with** `...`:
  [image]
- *Left clicking* the users lists in activity opens 'Define E-mail message', and clicking the address book icon here results in 'Select Users' window **without** `...`.
  [image]

Tested with SPD 2013.

Comment: Thank you, Aziz, but I could not reproduce your solution. What if you save and publish your workflow, then close and then open it again? I'm pretty sure you will see ellipses no matter how you access the users list

Comment: Hi @DenisMolodtsov. Sure I did test like that. What window gets opened when you click on users list in activity? Is it "Define E-mail message"?

Comment: yes, I left click on the users list within the activity. The pop-up window is titled "Define E-mail Message"

Comment: Wow, that's weird. Definitely it's something to investigate. My SPD is 15.0.4787.1000 32-bit, workflow is PoC site workflow @ O365 site. Could you test on new workflow, please?